# Is there a way to read emails from a outlook inbox on windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, outlook, electron

I am currently working on a small project, where I would like to read some date from emails from my outlook inbox on windows.

In python I used something like this to access a folder in the same level as my inbox folder:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Parent.Folders(foldername)  
messages = inbox.Items
```

Does something similar to win32com not exist in node/electron? I don't want to use the Microsoft exchange service or something similar and it's ok if outlook has to be open and authenticated for it to work.